# How to convert XML into JSON and put in to jQuery Datatables correctly

Tags: php, json, xml, dom, datatables

I got this here in stackoverflow. It works, but I want to put my json in to Datatables.

And there is an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

I want to know what im doing wrong.

**Here's my code**

```
function json2xml( $domNode ) {
foreach( $domNode -> childNodes as $node) {
 if ( $node -> hasChildNodes() ) { json2xml( $node ); }
  else {
   if ( $domNode -> hasAttributes() && strlen( $domNode -> nodeValue ) ) {
    $domNode -> setAttribute( "nodeValue", $node -> textContent );
    $node -> nodeValue;
   }
  }
 }
}

function jsonOut( $file ) {
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom -> loadXML( file_get_contents( $file ) );
 json2xml( $dom );
 header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
 return str_replace( "@", "", json_encode( simplexml_load_string( $dom -> 
 saveXML() ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );
}

$output = jsonOut( 'user.xml' );

echo( $output );
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the result of `simplexml_load_string()` to the encoding function? It's unlikely to be in a format that can be handled by `json_encode()`.

Comment: And your error message also gave you a file name and line number, telling you exactly where the error is. Perhaps you could share that...